# Why is Drogon free and his brothers Viserion and Rhaegal chained?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In *Game of Thrones* we have seen that Drogon is freely roaming and flying up in the sky, but what's the reason that we have not seen Viserion and Rhaegal flying freely in the sky?
Why are they chained?

Are they more dangerous than Drogon that they are chained?

Comment: related question - https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/67594/46039

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because [Drogon](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Drogon) was not in Meereen when she decided to chain the other two dragons and his exact whereabouts where unknown.

> Following Daenerys' conquest of Meereen, Drogon, who is now the size
>   of a small ship, kills and eats the goats of a local goatherd. (...)
>
> Dany is later dismayed to learn that Drogon has killed the daughter of
>   a goatherd. She tearfully confines the two smaller dragons to the
>   catacombs of the pyramid while Drogon remains at large, having last
>   been seen over the Black Cliffs.
>
> Daenerys confides in Daario Naharis that she has no idea where Drogon
>   has flown off to.

Drogon is not less dangerous than his brothers, he's actually the most dangerous:

> He is the largest and most aggressive of the three hatchlings.

Comment: Why they have never shown all the Three Dragons flying together and how come Drogon was flying outside and Rest of other two were inside so that they got chained why not everyone was free.

Comment: @DarkArmy Is this a question for me or the showrunners? :-)

Comment: I asked generally but if you could explain me this would be great.