# How did the two dragons get unchained?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

*Game of Thrones* - Season 6 Episode 9 - How did the remaining two dragons break their chains?

Is it mentioned anywhere in the book about this?

They've shown that the dragons followed after the wall was destroyed by the catapults from the ship. What happened to their chains?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> How did the remaining two dragons break their chains?

Tyrion unshackled them in season 6 episode 2 and it seemed that Drogon’s younger siblings (Rhaegal & Viserion) decided to just sit and wait for the right time.

Here is the clip of Tyrion unshackling chains.

Credits to a commenter:

> This event does not occur in books. In the books we see that the dragons have melted the chains themselves.